# Query to filter where value equals @param unless @param is other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a filter dropdown list with the following options in it:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Other

When the user selects an option I will run a simple SQL query to filter the data by that value such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Code = @Code
```

The only problem is that when the "Other" option is selected I need to show everything that does not have a code of 1,2,3,4, or 5.

The data looks like the following:

```
Id: 1, Name: Product 1, Code: 1
Id: 2, Name: Product 2, Code: 2
Id: 3, Name: Product 3, Code: null
Id: 4, Name: Product 4, Code: 3
Id: 5, Name: Product 5, Code: 12
```

If the user selects "Other" I need to only display: "Product 3" and "Product 5".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `OR` condition should accomplish that

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE (Code = @Code) OR (@Code = 'Other' AND Code NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5))
```

Comment: this does the trick, I haven't been around SQL in a few years so it just wouldn't come to me right away. Thanks!

Comment: `and @Code not in (1,2,3,4,5))` should be the column, not the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE (Code = @Code AND @Code IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')) OR
      (Code NOT IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') AND @Code = 'Other')
```

If `Code` is an integer, then the above may return a type conversion error.  In that case, I would recommend:

```
WHERE Code = TRY_CONVERT(INT, @Code) OR
      (Code NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND @Code = 'Other')
```

Comment: Code will always be an integer.

Comment: @BlakeRivell . . . Use the second solution.